# Spring can't resolve @Bean dependency for bean of type List?

Tags: java, spring

Simple test class showing my problem:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringTest.OptionalConfiguration.class)
public class SpringTest {
    static class Item extends Object {}

    @Configuration
    static class OptionalConfiguration {
        @Bean
        List<Item> someString() {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        @Bean
        Object foo(List<Item> obj) {
            return new Object();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testThis() {

    }
}
```

Result:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [SpringTest$Item] found for dependency
>   [collection of SpringTest$Item]: expected at least 1 bean which
>   qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency
>   annotations: {}

If I change from `List<Item>` to `Item`, things work.

Is this by design? Any workarounds? I'd need to provide a `List` of items - sometimes empty, sometimes with items, depending on runtime configuration.

I am aware that if I specify bean(s) with type Item, autowiring `List<Item>` works. However, I'd like to have a bean with type `List<Item>` (or if I can't have that, a `List`).

Using Spring 4.2.4.

Comment: The Spring source code is usually very clear -- it might be worth looking at the stack trace for that exception, finding the code where it looks for a qualifying bean, and seeing what it does. Hooray for Open Source!

Comment: Does using `@Qualifier` do any good?

Comment: @CollinD - I've just tried with`@Qualifier` - no it doesn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That snippet will work fine in Spring 4.3+. The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) states

> That said, as of 4.3, collection/map and array types can be matched
>   through Spring’s `@Autowired` type matching algorithm as well *[which
>   is also used for `@Bean` argument resolution]*, as long as the element
>   type information is preserved in `@Bean` return type signatures or
>   collection inheritance hierarchies. In this case, qualifier values can
>   be used to select among same-typed collections, as outlined in the
>   previous paragraph.

Pre 4.3, when Spring sees

```
@Bean
Object foo(List<Item> obj) {
```

it attempts to create a `List` object dynamically, containing all the `Item` beans found in the `ApplicationContext`. Your `ApplicationContext` doesn't contain any, so Spring reports an error.

Here are some workarounds. This

```
@Bean
Object foo() {
    List<Item> someString = someString();
    return new Object();
}
```

directly uses the cached bean factory method, `someString`.

This

```
@Resource(name = "someString")
private List<Item> items;
// and access 'items' wherever you need it in the configuration
```

works because

> If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not
>   primarily use @Autowired, even if is technically capable of referring
>   to a bean name through @Qualifier values. **Instead, use the JSR-250
>   @Resource annotation, which is semantically defined to identify a
>   specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type
>   being irrelevant for the matching process.** @Autowired has rather
>   different semantics: After selecting candidate beans by type, the
>   specified String qualifier value will be considered within those
>   type-selected candidates only, e.g. matching an "account" qualifier
>   against beans marked with the same qualifier label.

Comment: You are correct. It seems crazy to me that what I've tried won't work pre 4.3 - Spring 4.2.6 is not that old.

Comment: @eis I guess they considered it rare to have to declare a bean of a collection type and therefore never implemented it. It was more likely to declare a bunch of `Foo` beans and need to inject them all together.

Comment: Another workaround I found is
        `@Bean
        Object foo(ApplicationContext ctx) {
            List<Item> list = ctx.getBean("someString", List.class);
            return new Object();
        }`

  - not nice, but at least I can still have the same mechanism